# Stop automatic slide tab in the user Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, hover, slide

My tab is slide automaticly and I need Puss when hover and run automaticly leave hover by user now hove can Stop automatic slide tab in the user Hover? My html and css and js code this is:
HTML CODE

```
<ul id='tabs'>
<li class='on'>tab 1</li>
<li>tab 2</li>
<li>tab 3</li>
<li>tab 4</li>
<li>tab 5</li>
```

CSS CODE

```
#tabs { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#tabs li { float: left; background: #ddd; padding: 6px; }
#tabs li.on { background: #f90; color: #fff; }
```

JS (jQuery) CODE

```
$(function() {

//cache a reference to the tabs
var tabs = $('#tabs li');

//on click to tab, turn it on, and turn previously-on tab off
tabs.click(function() { $(this).addClass('on').siblings('.on').removeClass('on'); });

//auto-rotate every 5 seconds
setInterval(function() {

        //get currently-on tab
    var onTab = tabs.filter('.on');

        //click either next tab, if exists, else first one
    var nextTab = onTab.index() < tabs.length-1 ? onTab.next() :      tabs.first();
    nextTab.click();
}, 5000);
  });
```

Hove can use clearInterval in my code?

Comment: Could you take a few moments and [edit] your question? I've read it a couple of times and I honestly don't know what problem you're trying to solve; for example, what is "*Puss*"? It may help if you temporarily close the question and ask a friend or colleague, with better understanding of English, to review the question, that way you're able to fully explain in your native tongue and have feedback on the translation. While not being a native speaker of English isn't a reason to close the question, if we can't understand what you're asking there is a real chance the question will be closed.

Comment: @David Thomas puss is stop onmousever my code automaticly slide without stop onmosever or user hover

Answer (score 0):

This code will pause the automatic slide on hover of any of the tabs and restart when the mouse moves away`

```
//cache a reference to the tabs
var tabContainer = $('#tabs');
var tabs = $('#tabs li');

//on click to tab, turn it on, and turn previously-on tab off
tabs.click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('on').siblings('.on').removeClass('on');
});

//auto-rotate every 5 seconds
var slideInterval;

function initiateSlideInterval() {
    slideInterval = setInterval(function() {

        //get currently-on tab
        var onTab = tabs.filter('.on');

        //click either next tab, if exists, else first one
        var nextTab = onTab.index() < tabs.length - 1 ? onTab.next() : tabs.first();
        nextTab.click();
    }, 5000);

}
initiateSlideInterval();

tabContainer.mouseover(function() {
    clearInterval(slideInterval)
});
tabContainer.mouseout(function() {
    initiateSlideInterval();
});`
```